# Can't install MVVMCross on PCL project

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

After I create a PCL project in VS2012 with the following configuration:

[image: PCL configuration]

I try to add MVVMCross through Nuget installation, but the process rolls-back with this error:

[image]

I'm trying to install Hot Tuna Starter Pack for that matter.
I have installed Xamarin trial version a week ago.

Is this a Xamarin error supporting PCLs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your screenshots show that you have a VSMonoTouch PCL hack in place - it's likely that will be causing issues - especially with `net10` shown in the nuget log there. Try removing your VSMonoTouch XML files and then creating new projects for test.

Here is a setup that currently works for me - http://slodge.blogspot.ca/2013/04/my-current-pcl-setup-in-visual-studio.html

Note: It's likely that this post won't remain in-date for very long - Xamarin are releasing their PCL implementations at the moment.

Comment: Hey @Stuart thanks.
I tried removing the VSMonoTouch XML file from Profile104, 
also I tried the same setup that you gave, both didn't work, and got the exact same NuGet error.
I also updated my NuGet package manager.

Comment: OK, now everything seems to work. An overall restart was needed I suppose.
For anyone else that might see this, in the end, the state is now this:
1)I updated my NuGet package manager that was out of date.
2)In Profile104 I had the mono touch XML with the same content, but was named VSMonoTouch,Version=v1.0+.xml, now changed to MonoTouch,Version=v1.0+.xml. don't know if that made any difference..

Thanks Stuart

Comment: hey, I tried to install MvvmCross in Xamarin Studio this time, 
and got the same error trying to install to PCL project.
In VS2012 every thing still works fine though. 
I know you practice mainly in VS, but still worth a shot asking