# Can't install MVVMCross on PCL project only on XamarinStudio

Tags: .net, xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library, xamarin-studio

I was trying to install MvvmCross in a PCL project using Xamarin Studio.
Until now I was using visual studio 2012, I had a similar problem over there that was solved, through this post:  [Can't install MVVMCross on PCL project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906287/cant-install-mvvmcross-on-pcl-project)

But now the problem appears again in Xamarin Studio. The only fix I found is in this link: http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.PortableSupport/

a new version of MvvmCross from the awesome @Stuart Lodge.
But i couldn't manage to install the package because Xamarin Studio is lacking the Package Manager Console..

How do I install an MvvmCross on a PCL in Xamarin Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just found on the "N+1 days" of Stuart a video of how to fix the problem on Xamarin Studio here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UC2r4mmj3UI&feature=youtube_gdata

The fix is to open and edit the csproj. of the PCL project, and change the *TargetFrameworkProfile* element value to *Profile104*